# Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton"

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-design-library

I'm trying to use the new material , I've made the changes as below , this is my gradle :

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.ss.edu"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

and I changed my theme to this :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

when I add the MaterialButton to my layout and run my app , it run out with an error : `Didn't find class "com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton"`

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

To use `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`

Add below `dependencies` in your `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Also don't use the dependencies of `com.android.support` and `AndroidX` together

for information read this [**`Migrating to AndroidX`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Comment: You should not use the com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.

Comment: @KaranMer yes you are right added that in answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to migrate to androidX and want to continue using design support library you need to use `android.support.design.button.MaterialButton` instead of `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton`

Try using below code

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MATERIAL BUTTON"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_android_white_24dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

hope this helps

Comment: You should not use the com.android.support and com.google.android.material dependencies in your app at the same time.

Comment: Can u mention the reason, that would help !

Comment: it is mentioned in material io app guidelines check here https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/